# Laravel 4 Intervention package gets pixelated images when use fit() method

Tags: php, image-processing, laravel-4

I'm trying to resize an image using the method fit, and although I get the correct proportions, the result has an awful pixelated effect. How I can prevent this?

```
if ($imgHeight >= $imgWidth) {
    $img->fit((int) ($value[0] * $ratio), $value[0]);
 } else {
    $img->fit($value[0], (int) ($value[0] / $ratio));
 }
```

The original image is:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gs7z4s4jg1x6k6o/gallery-portraits-of-strangers-18.jpg?dl=0

And I take this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q9l17sf3r5x02fn/63_big.jpg?dl=0

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post pics.

Comment: Show us some examples of the original, the result, and what you'd have expected.

Comment: whats the image type ? png jpg ?

Comment: The image type is .jpg